# How to create iPad storyboard with iPhone also

Tags: xcode, ipad, storyboard, uistoryboard

Hi guys i have some little problem. So i use three storyboard in my project, there are iPhone 4s storyboard/iPhone 5 and i created for iPad also. So for choose storyboard i use this code:

```
UIStoryboard * mainStoryboard = nil ;   
CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
    mainStoryboard = [ UIStoryboard storyboardWithName : @ "iPhone5" bundle : nil ] ;

} else {
    mainStoryboard = [ UIStoryboard storyboardWithName : @ "iPhone4s" bundle : nil ] ;

}
self.window = [ [ UIWindow alloc ] initWithFrame : [ [ UIScreen mainScreen ] bounds ] ] ;
self.window.rootViewController = [ mainStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController ] ;
[ self.window makeKeyAndVisible ] ;
```

Work perfectly but not for iPad. After this code my storyboard for iPad does not see. How to choose iPad storyboard with all this storyboards. I understand my problem but i can not find good solve. How it's create? Thanks.

Also i tried this...but nothing.

```
if ([[UIDevice currentDevice] userInterfaceIdiom] ==UIUserInterfaceIdiomPhone)
{
    UIStoryboard * mainStoryboard = nil ;

         CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
           if (screenBounds.size.height == 568) {
          mainStoryboard = [ UIStoryboard storyboardWithName : @ "iPhone5" bundle : nil ] ;

          } else {
              mainStoryboard = [ UIStoryboard storyboardWithName : @ "iPhone4s" bundle : nil ] ;

          }

}
else
{
    UIStoryboard *appropriateStoryboard = [self storyboard];
    self.window.rootViewController = [appropriateStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    return YES;
    - (UIStoryboard *)storyboard
    {
        NSString *storyboardName = @"iPadMyBoard";
        if ([self isPad]) {
            storyboardName = [storyboardName stringByAppendingString:@""];
        }
        return [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
}

    -(BOOL)isPad
    {
        return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use this code

```
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{    
    UIStoryboard *appropriateStoryboard = [self storyboard];
    self.window.rootViewController = [appropriateStoryboard instantiateInitialViewController];
    return YES;
}

- (UIStoryboard *)storyboard
{
    NSString *storyboardName;
    if ([self isPad])
    {
        storyboardName = @"iPadMyBoard";
    }
    else
    {
        if ([self isPhone5])
        {
            storyboardName = @"iPhone5";
        }
        else
        {
            storyboardName = @"iPhone4s";
        }
    }
    return [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle:nil];
}

-(BOOL)isPad
{
    return (UI_USER_INTERFACE_IDIOM() == UIUserInterfaceIdiomPad);
}

-(BOOL)isPhone5
{
    CGRect screenBounds = [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds];
    if (screenBounds.size.height == 568){
        return YES;
    }
    return NO;
}
```

Comment: It choose iPad storyboard but storyboards for iPhone's - not.

Comment: So when i choose iPhone 4s for example i take storyboards from iPad